# How to see JSON of S3 Lifecycle rule created in console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lifecycle

I set up a Lifecycle rule on an S3 bucket by going to the bucket in the console -> Management -> Create lifecycle rule, and set it up in the configuration that I want it. How can I see the JSON that now defines this rule now that set up is done?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean something like `aws s3api get-bucket-lifecycle --bucket bucket-name` ?

Comment: What's the equivalent for the Powershell SDK? I tried Get-S3LifecycleConfiguration but that just returns the names of the rules attached to the bucket.

Comment: That is the equivalent command.  It returns an object.  If you want to convert it to JSON, you can use something like `Get-S3LifecycleConfiguration -bucket example-bucket | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4`

Answer (score 2):

To add to @Anon Coward's comment, this will be a perfect solution.

```
aws s3api get-bucket-lifecycle --bucket bucket-name --output json
```

Comment: What is the equivalent in Powershell SDK? I tried Get-S3LifecycleConfiguration but that just returns the name of the Lifecycle rules attaches to the bucket...